# Smallest Font-size in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, frontend, html, font-size

I'm now trying to create responsive webpages, but when using the Google Chrome to view these pages, a font-size problem occurred, any font size which is smaller than 12px will be displaying as 12px on Google Chrome.
I have tried the "-webkit-transform:scale (X value,Y value);" but the effect is not what I expected, it looks like the text is processed as a block, and the "text size" of this block was adjusted by setting x and y values which actually gave me a pretty strange result ...... does anyone have any good idea or solution? Thanks a lot!

Viktor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you don't use `PX` as unit of font-size, you can use viewport value instead.

If you want a really responsive website you probably better might want use another relative mesure such as: `vw, vh, or %` might work for you.

```
1vw = 1% of viewport width

1vh = 1% of viewport height

1vmin = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is smaller

1vmax = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is larger
```

---

```
h1 {
  font-size: 5.9vw;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 3.0vh;
}
p {
  font-size: 2vmin;
}
```

you even also could use CSS `media` specifiers for responsive styling such as like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

   h1 {
      font-size: 3em;
   }

   h2 {
      font-size: 2em;
   }
}
```

it depends on the behaviour you are looking for, if you could explain a little more of what you are really looking for, we could offer you a more accurate answer.

[This link](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-size/) might be usefull to you to make a choice! :)  and [this one](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) is where that info comes from

Comment: Hi Mate, thank you for the help, I was writing a new website for the company I'm working for; and I saw there're few types of font size measurement after the font size value, and I'm pretty wondering for in what situation is each of these measurement fitable?